# Cannot pass a parameter to the function through addEventListener

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following function:

```
export function myoutsideClickHandler(menuRef) {
    console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
    console.log(menuRef);
    document.addEventListener('click', (menuRef)=>test1(menuRef), false);
}
```

I can see that menuRef is printed and has value. So far so good.

Now in `test1()` function, I have:

```
export function test1(e, menuRef){
    console.log(menuRef);
}
```

In the console, I see undefined which means that menuRef has not been sent via addEventListener

Am I wrong with the way I am passing menuRef parameter?

Comment: `test1(menuRef)` and `test1(e, menuRef)` see your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are binding the event is wrong. `menuRef` in your click is going to be the event. You are not passing a second argument. Your click handler should be:

```
document.addEventListener('click', evt => test1(evt, menuRef), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function to trigger a callback function that requires multiple parameters. So in your case, changing your `myoutsideClickHandler()` function to the following should work:

```
export function myoutsideClickHandler(menuRef) {
    console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
    console.log(menuRef);
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        test1(e, menuRef);
    }, false);
}
```

However, I should note that you're not using event handlers correctly, they should be called and set up outside of click handler functions, so you may want to read up on that to avoid future issues.